# ASP.Net DatagridView Selection Links To Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2012

My datagrid is bound to a Sql-Server Database. The Datagrid shows information for each room. I've added an extra column at the end in asp.net which says Details. The user clicks details next to there desired room and it should open up a new webpage to that room. However there could be a problem, when the user looks for a room they do a search, how can i make it so that every time each details link is linked to a certain room.

I'm now thinking i need to actually add a new column inside that Sql database room table to maybe hold a link? is this possible anyone have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspx page :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRoomName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

code behind:

```
string strRoomId = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconstr"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from RoomDetails where RoomId = @RoomId", sqlCon);
sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomId", strRoomId);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: So i know how to do this with textboxes/labels. but how do i do this so it will show a datagridview of just that room? when it loads the room101 details page.

Comment: i tried this   GridView1.DataSource = dr;
               GridView1.DataBind();
 but nothing seems to be showing.

Comment: if you want to bind data to `GridView`
use `SqlDataAdapter` to get the data into `DataSet` , then 
you can use `GridView1.DataSource = ds;`

Comment: How do i populate the dataadaptor with dr information. Normally i would do this daCustomer.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers", CS);
            dsCustomer.Clear();
            daCustomer.Fill(dsCustomer);

Comment: But in this cause i want the dataadaptor to be filled with the same information as before. So it would show the row of data we clicked on details for.

Comment: I worked it out.  DA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Rooms where RoomNo = @RoomNo", sqlCon);
        DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("RoomNo", strRoomNo);

        DA.Fill(DS);

        GridView1.DataSource = DS;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a hyperlinkfield to you gridview

In the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property you will write the template address to the details page
eg "Details.aspx?id={0}" and in DataNavigateUrlFields you will write the name of the DB column which contains the ID of the row. The contents of the ID field will automatically replace the {0} part of the DataNavigateUrlFormatString

Example from MSDN:

```
<columns>

  <asp:boundfield datafield="OrderID" 
    headertext="OrderID"/>
  <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" 
    headertext="Customer ID"/>
  <asp:boundfield datafield="OrderDate" 
    headertext="Order Date"
    dataformatstring="{0:d}" />
  <asp:hyperlinkfield text="Details..."
    navigateurl="~\details.aspx"            
    headertext="Order Details"
    target="_blank" />

</columns>
```

Comment: Sorry im new to ASP.net and im abit confused. So i need to create a new page called Details, instead of having multiple pages from 101-110. How do i make this detailed page a template? :/ because the detail page is not going to hold the exact same information each time, so would i not need multiple different aspx pages? Is there a tutorial on this i can watch/look at

Comment: Sorry again, i just tested this and i see whats its doing now!

Comment: Just 1 last thing, so i now have RoomDetails.aspx?id=101, RoomDetails.aspx?id=102. How do i edit each of these pages, as in my panel i only have Roomdetails.aspx.

Comment: I tried adding a heading in roomdetails.aspx i set it to <h>101</h>, when i click on each of the details, they all show that room 101 heading. I need each of the pages to be unique.

Comment: @user1638362 , you can get the `id` from query string ,

eg: `string strroomId = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();`

based upon this `strroomId ` get the data from database and display it.

Comment: In Page_Load of roomdetails.aspx codebehind file write (if C#) int rooomNumber = int.Parse(Request.QueryString("id"));
Then you query the database for room specific information.

Comment: You need to put for example <asp:label>s on the details page and fill them with the information you want from the database. The first label would for example contain the room number.

Comment: I'm struggling abit again with this, is there a tutorial you know of which can walk me through this?

Comment: Could you show me how i can show each roomno, on the different roomdetails id pages. Then i might understand it better.

Comment: I found a tutorial that could suit you:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-filtering-across-two-pages-cs